# Data cleansing script

Tags: sql, database, oracle

**List all of the tools that have been rented but not returned for more than 3 years. Delete those tools**

I have a database with several tables. Some of these are `RENTAL_ORDERLINE`, `STOCK_TOOL` and `CATALOGUE`.

`RENTAL_ORDERLINE` has the date which tools were rented in and out and is linked to STOCK_TOOL via a `foreign key`.

Stock tool is linked to catalogue (which houses the Tool_Name) via a Foreign key.
I want to create a data cleansing script that lists all of the tools that have been rented but not returned for more than 3 years and delete these tools. I made a select statement that outputs the tools to be deleted but can't work a delete statement into it:

```
select rental_orderline.tool_id, catalogue.tool_name
from rental_orderline right outer join stock_tool
on stock_tool.tool_id = rental_orderline.tool_id
right outer join catalogue
on catalogue.catalogue_number = stock_tool.catalogue_number
where rental_orderline.date_out < add_months(sysdate, -36)
and rental_orderline.date_in is null;)
where rental_orderline.date_out < add_months(sysdate, -36)
and rental_orderline.date_in is null;
```

TOOL_ID TOOL_NAME

7 Mallet
8 Drill
9 Saw

I need to delete the output in the same query

```
delete from stock_tool 
where tool_id = 7, 8, 9;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
delete from stock_tool where tool_id IN (
    select rental_orderline.tool_id
    from rental_orderline right outer join stock_tool
    on stock_tool.tool_id = rental_orderline.tool_id
    right outer join catalogue
    on catalogue.catalogue_number = stock_tool.catalogue_number
    where rental_orderline.date_out < add_months(sysdate, -36)
    and rental_orderline.date_in is null;)
    where rental_orderline.date_out < add_months(sysdate, -36)
    and rental_orderline.date_in is null
);
```

?